# How do I uninstall USB wireless divers that didn't work?

Tags: wireless, command-line, drivers, uninstall

### Computer/OS stats:

- Old (5 yrs?) Dell desktop computer
- Ubuntu 12.04 is the ONLY OS installed
- Mem: 1.5GiB
- Processor: Intel Pentium 4 2.8GHz
- OS type: 32 bit
- Disk: 37.8GB

### Background info

I moved my desktop into another room without access to the ethernet cord I previously was using. I was hoping it would be a simple thing to get a wireless card to access the internet with this computer, but it has been difficult and I haven't had success yet.

I tried 3 different wireless USB adapters; unfortunately, I can't remember all of the details of those 3 because I already returned them to the store since I couldn't get them to work. I know that the companies were Belkin, Linksys and Netgear. I was trying to use the instructions on this and other various sites to download drivers, using the program (WINE), but honestly I am a complete newbie at all of this and didn't know what I was doing (I still don't), so I don't know exactly what I installed or where it is.

I finally returned them all of the failed-attempt wireless cards to the store and ordered a D-Link Wireless N Nano USB adapter online, after I had originally looked for the USB wireless adapters from this site: https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/wireless-networking-gnulinux

Unfortunately, I think Amazon sent me the wrong one because the D-Link I have in front of my says nothing about being compatible with Linux; so I'm probably going to send it back and try again for a Linux supported wireless USB adapter (what I THOUGHT I ordered from Amazon).

### Question

the latest wireless router instructs me to uninstall all previous related programs. Since I installed them using the Ctrl+Alt+T and didn't know what I was doing, I cannot find them to uninstall them with the USC. I tried the command:

```
apt-get --purge remove linksye
```

as well as other possible program names, but I don't even know what the actual program names *were*. I don't know how to find them, either.

So my guess is I need to:

1. Find out what the names of the 3 programs were
2. Uninstall them - all using the Terminal

I have no idea how to do this. Help please?

Comment: You should not have to uninstall any software. Those instructions were probably directed at Windows or Mac users. Simply plugging the device in may work, what happens when you do that? What is the result of `lsusb` (typed into the terminal from Ctrl+Alt+T) when the device is plugged in? Be very careful when ordering "Linux-supported" hardware online and do extensive research; try to get personal testimonies. Often, the device may be supported by Linux, but you will still need to download third-party drivers or mess around with config files.

Answer (score 1):

Using WINE to install drivers for a wireless card will almost certainly not work, as you ideally want the hardware to interface with your OS natively. I'd suggest looking for linux versions of the drivers rather than attempting to use Windows versions wrapped in WINE.

As for removing the drivers, a good place to start would be to look in whatever directory you have set up for WINE to use as it's C:\ drive, and look in the standard folders there (e.g. C:\Program Files\, etc.), and you should be able to just delete those folders.

Alternatively, you could just remove the whole folder you have set up as your WINE C:\ drive and reinstall, though you need to be careful that you won't remove any other programs you've installed using WINE.